# How to check if a file exists in an RPM .spec file?

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, rpm-spec

I have a spec file that needs to check if an older version of a file exists and if so delete it. For some reason, it is running the delete command regardless of whether the file exists and printing a "no such file or directory" error, which leads me to believe my if statement checking if the file exists is at fault. Here is my code.

```
if [ -e "/foo/bar/file.zip" ]; then
    rm -rf /foo/bar/file.zip
fi
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is printing a "no such file or directory" error? That `rm` command cannot be doing that. Also you don't need `-r` for files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `rm -rf` command **cannot** be the source of that error message because `-f` tells `rm` to never fail (and to never print such error messages, try it locally `rm -f /this/is/some/path/that/does/not/exist; echo $?`). (This means, of course, that the test for file existence itself is unnecessary since `rm -f` does not care.

Additionally you do not need the `-r` flag if you are deleting a file (and it is safer not to include it (or `-f`) when you do not need them.

So something else must be printing that message. Do you use that file anywhere else? Does anything from the old package's `%preun` use it perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

```
[ -f /foo/bar/file.zip ] && rm -f /foo/bar/file.zip || echo "File Not Found"
```

Comment: Why -f instead of -e?

Comment: Refer [http://www.cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-existence-of-file-in-bash/)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you didn't add a space between the file path and `-e`:

```
if [ -e"/foo/bar/file.zip" ]; then
    rm -rf /foo/bar/file.zip
fi
```

It would be synonymous to this which is always true:

```
if [ -n "-e/foo/bar/file.zip" ]; then
    rm -rf /foo/bar/file.zip
fi
```